# How to pass the variable in dbmate?

Tags: python

I've planned to use [dbmate](https://github.com/amacneil/dbmate) for my project. I am using multi tenant db architecture . Each client has a separate database.

My question is:

For each client, I want to run dbmate with their client/subscriber_id dynamically. How do I replace %subscriber_id1% with the current subscriber_id in dbmate. (Note: I have tried to setting an env variables and dbmate.yml and both are not working and there is no documentation about this in the official site)

```
-- 20230713031900_check_dbmate_table.sql

-- migrate:up

SET @subscriber_id = %subscriber_id1%;

INSERT into master_data ( subscriber_id, name) VALUES ( @subscriber_id, 'test1');
```

Comment: I cannot tell how the first code block relates to the second code block. Also, the `dbmate` app manages changes to a database schema. Your question implies you want to use it to manage changes to the data -- not the schema -- of a database. It is true that I have never used `dbmate` so I might be missing something obvious but I think your question needs clarification.